# Rails: Appropriate / conventional way to act on notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've built a Stripe SaaS app a bit like Byron Bowerman's [stripe-example](https://github.com/BM5k/stripe-example).

Notifications from Stripe are called "webhooks", and include information like whether payments have succeeded or failed.  In my app they are received by the [stripe-event gem](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) which then passes the information to a Webhook model to be saved in the database.

I want to use these events to trigger actions:

- email to user
- update User model
- etc.

The question is which class should take these actions, and how should it be informed?

There are a few options:

**1) Within Webhook model**

Easy, but feels outside what responsibility of this class should be.

**2) Webhook Observer(s)**

One observer, or separate ones for different actions?

**3) Rails Notifications**

The Webhook model could send out an `ActiveSupport::Notification` each time it receives a webhook.  This could be subscribed to by a class anywhere in the application.  If I went this route would it be appropriate to do this in the User model, the UsersController, or somewhere else?

A worry I have with this approach is that in his [railscast on notifications](http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) Ryan Bates recommends that "notifications are best used for logging and for code that doesn’t modify the application’s core behaviour."

**4) ...?**

What do you advise?